# Extracting .gz files recursively from subdirectories

Tags: shell, recursion

I want to extract .gz files from subdirectories when I provide the directory path such that it goes through all the subdirectories and extracts .gz files, I am struggling in writing  the code in shell.

Comment: Actually the structure is dir/subdir and the sub directories contain the .gz files , so I want to extract those.

Comment: If the answer below helped you you should consider accepting it so your question doesn't keep floating around as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

`find subdir -name \\*.gz -exec gzip -d {} \;`